# How is the data stored in NGXS store? what is the memory limit of ngxs store? where is the ngxs store memory in browser?

Tags: angular, ngrx, store, state-management, ngxs

I tried to learn NGRX from NGRX site, but I didn't get an proper answer for how and where the NGRX storing the data. And also the limit of Data ehich we can store in NGRX store.

Comment: this demo will help you to learn ngrx https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hello & Welcome to SO,

First of all, [NGRX](https://github.com/ngrx) & [NGXS](https://github.com/ngxs) are two different projects, even though they share ~*almost* the same aim (state management and the **SSOT** practice for Angular applications).

Now for you questions:

***1. **How is the data stored in NGXS store** ?***

The state in Redux-like (ngrx, ngxs..) applications is stored in browser's memory, i.e. it is just a variable (more precisely: an object) that persists in memory and referenced by all redux functions.

An object that's is also to say if you refresh the page, that state gets wiped out.

***2.  what is the memory limit of ngxs store ?***

Depends on your browser's memory, but I think it should be unreachable in normal app cases (unless you make some stress tests on your browser, or you have a ~limited resources hardware)

***3. where is the ngxs store memory in browser***

Already answered in the first question.

---

*for more informations / details, kindly check:*

[Add Large Amounts of Data in the App State in Redux](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/add-large-amounts-of-data-in-the-app-state-in-redux)

[What's the maximum memory size of the redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719688/whats-the-maximum-memory-size-of-the-redux-store)

[What is the maximum size of the redux store in a react native application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67280304/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-redux-store-in-a-react-native-application?rq=1)

[NGXS state size and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945876/ngxs-state-size-and-performance)